# GeoServer WMS: Retrieved GeoTIFF band contains integer values instead of floats

Tags: geoserver, wms, layers, gdal-translate

I am using gdal_translate to import a GeoTIFF into an oracle database. The import as well as the layer creation in GeoServer works without errors. GeoServer correctly recognizes the band data type as "Real 32 bits".

Unfortunately when I try to retrieve the layer via WMS as GeoTIFF and analyse it the float values are gone and the bands contain only integer values, which is not useful for further image processing.

Any ideas how I can retrieve the bands with their orifinal data types via WMS?

Comment: Use WCS, this is essentially a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169863/geoserver-wms-get-original-raster-image-in-highest-resolution

Comment: i don't think it's a duplicate, because I don't need the source image, but the image in the original data type

Comment: That question has a misleading title, they did not want source image, they say they need to define bounding box.

Comment: Both questions fail to understand that WMS returns a picture of the data not the data itself, if you want data use the WCS

Comment: Web Map Service is made for delivering maps for human eyes. With some WMS servers it is possible to configure 32-bit outputformat for WMS http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/outputformat.html. With GeoServer it is not possible http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html. If you want data use the WCS is good advice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found a GeoServer WMS extentsion (DDS/BIL(World Wind Data Formats) Extension) which I will try next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other people said above, you need to use WCS not WMS for retaining the original bit depth of the source raster data.

WMS, one way or the other, will perform a rendering. Depending on the chosen output format, you can get 8 bits or 16 bits unsigned but you should never get floats or double or signed data.

The only exception might be DDS format for WorldWind which is peculiar and bypasses rendering.

Simone.